# Azure LogicApp Fails on SQL Connection

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am trying to call a stored procedure in Azure Logic App. However, whenever I am trying to connect to DB & select procedure or execute app I get the following error.

`

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "Can not add property StartTime to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. Property with the same name already exists on object.\r\nclientRequestId: 99825289-bbe8-4b91-8323-075e8cacd09c",
  "source": "sql-logic-cp-centralindia.logic-ase-centralindia.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
```

`

I face the same error if try to execute SQL select query instead of stored procedure.

Here is the code of the logic app. Any suggestions?

`

```
{
  "$connections": {
    "value": {
      "sql": {
        "connectionId": "/subscriptions/XXXX/resourceGroups/Reports/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql",
        "connectionName": "sql",
        "id": "/subscriptions/XXXX/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralindia/managedApis/sql"
      }
    }
  },
  "definition": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "actions": {
      "Execute_stored_procedure": {
        "inputs": {
          "host": {
            "connection": {
              "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
            }
          },
          "method": "post",
          "path": "/datasets/default/procedures/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[dbo].[SchoolDataDump]'))}"
        },
        "runAfter": {},
        "type": "ApiConnection"
      },
      "Response": {
        "inputs": {
          "statusCode": 200
        },
        "kind": "http",
        "runAfter": {
          "Execute_stored_procedure": [
            "Succeeded"
          ]
        },
        "type": "Response"
      }
    },
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "outputs": {},
    "parameters": {
      "$connections": {
        "defaultValue": {},
        "type": "Object"
      }
    },
    "triggers": {
      "manual": {
        "inputs": {
          "schema": {}
        },
        "kind": "Http",
        "type": "Request"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that was a tricky mistake.  After some struggle, I was able to figure out the issue. 
In my select query, I had two fields with the same name. That was causing the issue in creating output JSON.

I had two fields in the query like below

`Select .. SM.StartTime,... SS.StartTime from tables .. joins`

SQL output had two times StartTime in SQL output. So I added an alias as below and it solved the issue.

`Select .. SM.StartTime,... SS.StartTime as SessionStartTime from tables .. joins`